# Cambiar el orden de dd/mm/aaaa por aaaa/mm/dd en jquery para calcular años

Tags: php, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
/**
 * Funcion que devuelve true o false dependiendo de si la fecha es correcta.
 * Tiene que recibir el dia, mes y año
 */
function isValidDate(day,month,year)
{
    var dteDate;

    // En javascript, el mes empieza en la posicion 0 y termina en la 11 
    //   siendo 0 el mes de enero
    // Por esta razon, tenemos que restar 1 al mes
    month=month-1;
    // Establecemos un objeto Data con los valore recibidos
    // Los parametros son: año, mes, dia, hora, minuto y segundos
    // getDate(); devuelve el dia como un entero entre 1 y 31
    // getDay(); devuelve un num del 0 al 6 indicando siel dia es lunes,
    //   martes, miercoles ...
    // getHours(); Devuelve la hora
    // getMinutes(); Devuelve los minutos
    // getMonth(); devuelve el mes como un numero de 0 a 11
    // getTime(); Devuelve el tiempo transcurrido en milisegundos desde el 1
    //   de enero de 1970 hasta el momento definido en el objeto date
    // setTime(); Establece una fecha pasandole en milisegundos el valor de esta.
    // getYear(); devuelve el año
    // getFullYear(); devuelve el año
    dteDate=new Date(year,month,day);

    //Devuelva true o false...
    return ((day==dteDate.getDate()) && (month==dteDate.getMonth()) && (year==dteDate.getFullYear()));
}

/**
 * Funcion para validar una fecha
 * Tiene que recibir:
 *  La fecha en formato ingles yyyy-mm-dd
 * Devuelve:
 *  true-Fecha correcta
 *  false-Fecha Incorrecta
 */
function validate_fecha(fecha)
{
    var patron=new RegExp("^(19|20)+([0-9]{2})([-])([0-9]{1,2})([-])([0-9]{1,2})$");

    if(fecha.search(patron)==0)
    {
        var values=fecha.split("-");
        if(isValidDate(values[2],values[1],values[0]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Esta función calcula la edad de una persona y los meses
 * La fecha la tiene que tener el formato yyyy-mm-dd que es
 * metodo que por defecto lo devuelve el <input type="date">
 */
function calcularEdad()
{
    var fecha=document.getElementById("user_date").value;
    if(validate_fecha(fecha)==true)
    {
        // Si la fecha es correcta, calculamos la edad
        var values=fecha.split("-");
        var dia = values[2];
        var mes = values[1];
        var ano = values[0];

        // cogemos los valores actuales
        var fecha_hoy = new Date();
        var ahora_ano = fecha_hoy.getYear();
        var ahora_mes = fecha_hoy.getMonth()+1;
        var ahora_dia = fecha_hoy.getDate();

        // realizamos el calculo
        var edad = (ahora_ano + 1900) - ano;
        if ( ahora_mes < mes )
        {
            edad--;
        }
        if ((mes == ahora_mes) && (ahora_dia < dia))
        {
            edad--;
        }
        if (edad > 1900)
        {
            edad -= 1900;
        }

        // calculamos los meses
        var meses=0;
        if(ahora_mes>mes)
            meses=ahora_mes-mes;
        if(ahora_mes<mes)
            meses=12-(mes-ahora_mes);
        if(ahora_mes==mes && dia>ahora_dia)
            meses=11;

        // calculamos los dias
        var dias=0;
        if(ahora_dia>dia)
            dias=ahora_dia-dia;
        if(ahora_dia<dia)
        {
            ultimoDiaMes=new Date(ahora_ano, ahora_mes, 0);
            dias=ultimoDiaMes.getDate()-(dia-ahora_dia);
        }

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Tienes "+edad+" años, "+meses+" meses y "+dias+" días";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="La fecha "+fecha+" es incorrecta";
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="date" name="user_date" id="user_date" />
    <input type="button" value="Calcular edad" onclick="javascript:calcularEdad();" />

    <!-- div donde mostraremos el resultado -->
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

El cual requiero cambiar el orden del input box para el formato `aaaa/mm/dd` o `yyyy/mm/dd` es decir que inicie primero el año mes y dia para hacer un calculo de años.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  
  <!-- Librerías jQuery y jQuery UI -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#user_date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
      });
    </script>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
/**
 * Funcion que devuelve true o false dependiendo de si la fecha es correcta.
 * Tiene que recibir el dia, mes y año
 */
function isValidDate(day,month,year)
{
    var dteDate;

    // En javascript, el mes empieza en la posicion 0 y termina en la 11 
    //   siendo 0 el mes de enero
    // Por esta razon, tenemos que restar 1 al mes
    month=month-1;
    // Establecemos un objeto Data con los valore recibidos
    // Los parametros son: año, mes, dia, hora, minuto y segundos
    // getDate(); devuelve el dia como un entero entre 1 y 31
    // getDay(); devuelve un num del 0 al 6 indicando siel dia es lunes,
    //   martes, miercoles ...
    // getHours(); Devuelve la hora
    // getMinutes(); Devuelve los minutos
    // getMonth(); devuelve el mes como un numero de 0 a 11
    // getTime(); Devuelve el tiempo transcurrido en milisegundos desde el 1
    //   de enero de 1970 hasta el momento definido en el objeto date
    // setTime(); Establece una fecha pasandole en milisegundos el valor de esta.
    // getYear(); devuelve el año
    // getFullYear(); devuelve el año
    dteDate=new Date(year,month,day);

    //Devuelva true o false...
    return ((day==dteDate.getDate()) && (month==dteDate.getMonth()) && (year==dteDate.getFullYear()));
}

/**
 * Funcion para validar una fecha
 * Tiene que recibir:
 *  La fecha en formato ingles yyyy-mm-dd
 * Devuelve:
 *  true-Fecha correcta
 *  false-Fecha Incorrecta
 */
function validate_fecha(fecha)
{
    var patron=new RegExp("^(19|20)+([0-9]{2})([-])([0-9]{1,2})([-])([0-9]{1,2})$");

    if(fecha.search(patron)==0)
    {
        var values=fecha.split("-");
        if(isValidDate(values[2],values[1],values[0]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Esta función calcula la edad de una persona y los meses
 * La fecha la tiene que tener el formato yyyy-mm-dd que es
 * metodo que por defecto lo devuelve el <input type="date">
 */
function calcularEdad()
{
    var fecha=document.getElementById("user_date").value;
    if(validate_fecha(fecha)==true)
    {
        // Si la fecha es correcta, calculamos la edad
        var values=fecha.split("-");
        var dia = values[2];
        var mes = values[1];
        var ano = values[0];

        // cogemos los valores actuales
        var fecha_hoy = new Date();
        var ahora_ano = fecha_hoy.getYear();
        var ahora_mes = fecha_hoy.getMonth()+1;
        var ahora_dia = fecha_hoy.getDate();

        // realizamos el calculo
        var edad = (ahora_ano + 1900) - ano;
        if ( ahora_mes < mes )
        {
            edad--;
        }
        if ((mes == ahora_mes) && (ahora_dia < dia))
        {
            edad--;
        }
        if (edad > 1900)
        {
            edad -= 1900;
        }

        // calculamos los meses
        var meses=0;
        if(ahora_mes>mes)
            meses=ahora_mes-mes;
        if(ahora_mes<mes)
            meses=12-(mes-ahora_mes);
        if(ahora_mes==mes && dia>ahora_dia)
            meses=11;

        // calculamos los dias
        var dias=0;
        if(ahora_dia>dia)
            dias=ahora_dia-dia;
        if(ahora_dia<dia)
        {
            ultimoDiaMes=new Date(ahora_ano, ahora_mes, 0);
            dias=ultimoDiaMes.getDate()-(dia-ahora_dia);
        }

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Tienes "+edad+" años, "+meses+" meses y "+dias+" días";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="La fecha "+fecha+" es incorrecta";
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- El tipo date se cambia a text -->
    <input type="text" name="user_date" id="user_date" />

    <input type="submit" value="Calcular edad" onclick="javascript:calcularEdad();" />

    <!-- div donde mostraremos el resultado -->
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Recomiendo ejecutar a pantalla completa. Existe bastante documentación sobre **datepicker**; se puede cambiar el lenguaje, restricciones de formato, entre otras cosas.

#Consideraciones#

El **formato de presentación** de las fechas depende del navegador y la configuración local del usuario

- Chrome y Opera muestran un datepicker con el calendario en formato local.
- Firefox, Internet Explorer 11 y versiones anteriores no muestran un datepicker.

Por otro lado, **HTML5** recoge los datos del `input date` en formato `yyyy-mm-dd`, especificado por **RFC3339**.

En conclusión, no se puede cambiar el formato de presentación sin el uso de librerías externas.

**Referencias**

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_date.asp

RFC3339: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6

Comment: tu calculo de edad esta incorrecto, si yo pongo que nací ayer 30-Noviembre (hoy 01-Diciembre), me dice que tengo 1 mes y 2 días de nacido, lo cual la respuesta correcta seria que solo tengo 2 días de nacido

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="date" id="my_date">
<input type="button" id="get_date" value="Dame la fecha">
<script>
  $(document).on('click','#get_date',function(){
    var fecha = $('#my_date').val();
    alert(fecha);
  })
</script>
```

Eso te regresa lo que necesitas, lo hice con Jquery.

Comment: Eso no hace nada más que recoger el valor que hayas puesto en el campo de texto. No tiene nada que ver con la pregunta